# Is it possible to set the underline offset when using Font.UNDERLINED?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-jde

Is it possible to set the underline offset when using **Font.UNDERLINED**? I am using the following to make the font underlined:

```
LabelField lf = new LabelField("Forgot your password?");
lf.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINED));
```

The above code produces

[image]

I want the underline to appear at the font's bottommost position. Like this:

[image]

Solutions I can think of:

1. One possible solution would be to extend `LabelField` and override its `paint()` method. Something in the form:

   ```
   paint(Graphics g) {
       super.paint(g);
       g.drawLine(...);
   }
   ```

   The above code will work fine as long as `LabelField`'s contents will occupy a single line.    It will become very messy once the contents will occupy multiple lines. Therefore, I am looking for a more appropriate solution.
2. Another solution would be to write a new field similar to `LabelField` from scratch.

Comment: Eventually, I ended up writing a custom label fields class. The class doesn't extend `LabelField` and I don't use Font.UNDERLINED in it. In its `paint()` method, I am drawing the underline using `Graphics#drawLine()` method for each and every line of my field.